# javascript object array conversion in es6/7

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am new in Javascript, I usually need to handle conversion between object and array, but how can I do it more elegant or clean in ES6/7 such as use `Spread syntax` or `lodash`..., rather than use for loop iteration.(since I don't like mutable stuff.)

I want to convert the below object:

```
{
  book: {
    1001: 'a', 
    1002: 'b', 
    1003: 'c'
  },
  game: {
    1001: 'a'
  }
}
```

to below array of object:

```
[
  {
    category: 'book',
    item: [
      { id: 1001, name: 'a' },
      { id: 1002, name: 'b' },
      { id: 1003, name: 'c' }
    ]
  }, 
  {
    category: 'game',
    item: [
      { id: 1001, name: 'a' }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Well what  you want is not valid... assume you want it as an array, not object.

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking for. The first edit at least turned your desired state into valid data but you've changed it back into something invalid.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Updated to array of object.

Answer (score 2):

You could build new objects and map the inner objects as new items.

```js
var data = { book: { 1001: 'a', 1002: 'b', 1003: 'c' }, game: { 1001: 'a' } },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(([category, item ]) => 
            ({ category, item: Object.entries(item).map(([id, name]) => ({ id, name })) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```